# How do I solve the broken dependency on 'net-snmp-agent-libs' for centos 6?

Tags: centos, dependencies

I have net-snmp 5.5 installed. But the application I'm trying to install depend on net-snmp-agent-libs. I can find it anywhere. The application instruction says if I compile net-snmp from source I shouldn't have a dependency problem.

I tried to compile net-snmp from source but it didn't solve this problem.

Where can I find net-snmp-agent-libs rpm that is of the same version as my net-snmp (5.5)?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to install?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, kamailio-snmpstats

Comment: And where did you get it from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, rpmbuild from modified source code. They aren't from the kamailio's build service.

Comment: You probably started with the wrong spec file, then. That package is in Fedora and EL 7, but not in EL 6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, En.... I need to install it on centos 6. I know it can be done because I tried to install kamailio-snmpstats from their build service and it worked fine. To compile net-snmp 5.5, I downloaded the source from their official site and used the spec file in the source. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
In case someone wants to know:
There is a bug in the spec file I was using.
As MichaelHampton pointed out in the comments, net-snmp-agent-libs is a fedora package. There is no such rpm in centos repository.

The bug in the spec file is this :

```
%if 0%{?centos}
Requires:      net-snmp-agent-libs
%else
Requires:      net-snmp-libs
```

where centos should be fedora .